# How can I prevent parts of the subdivision from snapping to edges?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

When creating my first humanoid model, an area near the feet would not adjust to the result, instead snapping to the edges. How do I resolve this?
[image: feet]

Comment: Hey Jeth! Have you tried selecting all your mesh with pressing A and then M - Merge by distance? Maybe this will fix it

Comment: Do you mean that the edge is sharp? Maybe overlapping vertices, or inner faces, or inverted normals, but maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Please make it more clear what you mean by 'Snapping to Edges'. Do you mean you want all your geometry to be smoother?

Comment: File of project: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=EwkwAmmO" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/EwkwAmmO/)

Comment: Addressing Robin Betts, the image shows how despite all the other geometry in this model has become more circular and shrunk compared to the base. The area around the ankle has retained adherence to it's edges. I just need it to conform to the rest subdivision modifier's adjustments. Sorry if I don't make sense or sound inexperienced, I pretty much just started working with blender two days ago and don't know a whole lot.